# How to get the substring between two markers and repeat the process N times in Python

Tags: python, substring, repeat

I am a new Python user. I have A string in below, where I want to extract the data between **name_with_branch** and **country_code**. So I am using this below Query. But by this way I can only get the first element like **Burger Mania - Bashundhara**. I want to get the 2nd and 3rd elements in the same way. How can I Get it? Also if the string has N times name_with_branch and country_code than how can I get 1st to N number of elements?

**String input:**

```
{name_with_branch: Burger Mania - Bashundhara, country_code: bd, city: dhaka}, {name_with_branch: Pizza Go - Bashundhara, country_code: bd, city: dhaka}, {name_with_branch: Magpie Restaurant - Bashundhara, country_code: bd, city: dhaka}.....N
```

**Desire Output:**

```
    Burger Mania - Bashundhara
    Pizza Go - Bashundhara
    Magpie Restaurant - Bashundhara
   .
   .
   .
   .
   N
```

**Code:**

```
s = "{name_with_branch: Burger Mania - Bashundhara, country_code: bd, city: dhaka}, {name_with_branch: Pizza Go - Bashundhara, country_code: bd, city: dhaka}, {name_with_branch: Magpie Restaurant - Bashundhara, country_code: bd, city: dhaka}"
start = s.find("name_with_branch:") + len("name_with_branch:")
end = s.find(",")
substring = s[start:end]
print(substring)
```

**Code Output:**

```
Burger Mania - Bashundhara
```

Comment: You asked almost the same question earlier. The dupe I closed your other question with, gives you plenty of answers what to do to achieve your goal. Why did it not help? What did you try using the solutions from the dupe? Why did they not solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, extremely sorry, I am not getting what I am expecting. I am using below query:

s = "{name_with_branch: Burger Mania - Bashundhara, country_code: bd, city: dhaka}, {name_with_branch: Pizza Go - Bashundhara, country_code: bd, city: dhaka}"
x=0
y = len(s)
for x in range(y):
  start = s.find("name_with_branch:") + len("name_with_branch:") + x
  end = s.find(",") + x
  substring = s[start:end]
  lenth = len("name_with_branch:") + len(substring) + len(",")
  lenth1 = len("name_with_branch: Burger Mania - Bashundhara,")
  print(substring)
  x = x + lenth @PatrickArtner

Comment: use `start = s.find("name_with_branch:", startpos)` with a startpos of 0 to begin with. If > -1 use `end = s.find(",", start+len("name_with_branch:"))` and set `startpos=end`. Add the slice `s[start:end]` to a list.Loop over this until you get -1 for `start = s.find("name_with_branch:", startpos)` - in that case break from your `while True:`. Print the list. Done.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. My loop is not breaking. Can you please tell me what's wrong? `s = "{name_with_branch: Burger Mania - Bashundhara, country_code: bd, city: dhaka}, {name_with_branch: Pizza Go - Bashundhara, country_code: bd, city: dhaka}"
x=0
y = len(s)
startpos = 0 
while True:
  if startpos > -1:
      start = s.find("name_with_branch:", startpos) 
      end = s.find(",", start+ len("name_with_branch:"))
      substring = [s[start:end]]
      print(start)
      print(end)
      startpos=end
      print(startpos)
  if startpos <= -1:
      break    
print(substring)`